# How can i take a full name in String under case statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
System.out.println("Enter 1 to Add a Record");
System.out.println("Enter 2 to Print the Records");
System.out.println("Enter 3 to Delete a Record");
System.out.println("Enter 4 to Edit a Record");
int x=abir.nextInt();
switch(x){
  case 1:
    System.out.println("Enter Student Name");
    String x1=abir.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Student Id");
    String x2=abir.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Student Department name");
    String x3=abir.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Student Contact info");
    String x4=abir.nextLine();
    bo.AddInlist(x1,x2,x3,x4);
    break;
  case 2:
    bo.PrintRecord();
    break;
  case 3:
    System.out.println("enter your desire deleting id");
    String x5=abir.nextLine();
    bo.DeleteRecord(x5);
    break;
  case 4:
    System.out.println("enter your desire Edited id");
    String x6=abir.nextLine();
    bo.EditRecord(x6);
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("Wrong Entry.. Follow the Instructions");
    System.out.println();
}
```

So, according to the rule, if user press 1 then first it would take x1 but here it takes x2.. My question is how can i take a full name in string in that code under case 1..
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It's because you didn't consume the line separator when entering the number.

When you provide the first input on your keyboard you are doing this:

1. Press <kbd>1</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

When pressing enter, you pass a line separator.

Now `nextInt()` will consume the '1' and the line separator (which is still in the buffer) token will be consumed by the first `nextLine()` call in your first case in the switch.

That's why you go to "Enter StudentId" directly.

To fix this, add a `nextLine()` call just after `nextInt()`:

```
int x=abir.nextInt();
abir.nextLine(); //consume the line separator
```

Comment: You can also grab the number as a String, and then parse the integer value from it.  In either case, it is always a good idea that the input provided by the user is a numeric value before using. Otherwise, the code could break.

Answer (score 0):

It is like what ZouZou said so the code for that part will be

```
  case 1:
        System.out.println("Enter Student Name");
        String x1=abir.nextLine();
        x1 = abir.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Name:" + x1);
        System.out.println("Enter Student Id");
        String x2=abir.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Student Department name");
        String x3=abir.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Student Contact info");
        String x4=abir.nextLine();
        bo.AddInlist(x1,x2,x3,x4);

        break;
```